# how to add integer in front of another integer in c#

Tags: c#

How to add integer in front of another integer let's say 7, and adding other numbers to it. For Example, if 1 is added in front of 7 it becomes 17. and then find that its prime number or not. If 3 is added in front of 17 it becomes 317 and so on

Comment: if it is smaller than 10, then multiply with 10 before adding. If it is smaller than 100, then multiply the value by 100 before adding. Like 7<10 so 1*10+7=17 and 17<100 so 3*100+17 = 317

Comment: Is this number an `int` or a `string`?

Comment: numbers are the user input

Answer (score 4):

Find out how much larger one number has to be to fit in front of the other, then you multiply by that factor and add the other number:

```
int n1 = 3;
int n2 = 17;

int x = 1;
while (x <= n2) {
  x *= 10;
}

int result = n1 * x + n2; // 317
```

Answer (score 2):

let's say your number is 7

```
int myNumber = 7;
```

you want to add 1 in front of it;

```
int toAdd = 1;
```

all you have to do is say

```
myNumber = toAdd * 10 + myNumber;
```

that means:

```
1 * 10 = 10; 10 + 7 = 17;
```

**Last Edit**

As I discussed in the comments, my first solution was working only if you try to add one digit in front of another integer/digit. If we try to add an integer in front of another integer eg.: 17 and 17 will fail because:
17 * 10 +17 = 170 + 17 = 187, which is not equal with 1717 the correct answer

A general solution for this is to multiply with 10 to the power number of digits your number has
Ex:

If I want to add 17 in front of 111 the result should be 17111;

```
111 has 3 digits -> 10^3 = 1000
```

than we multiply 17 with 1000

```
17000 + 111 =17111
```

you can check for the number of digits a number has with a while loop

```
int digits=0;
while(number >0)
{
number = number/10;
digits++;
}

myNumber = toAdd* 10^digits + myNumber;
```

Comment: @Raphael: true. it works if you want to add a digit in front of another digit/integer. is a way to avoid casting to string, but not working in case of integers, as you said in your example.In this case you have to multiply with 10 to power of number of digits your number has. 17 has 2 digits =>  10 ^2 = 100; 17*100+17 = 1717 :)

Comment: @AndreiAndrei, how about updating your answer with the info from your comment ;)

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus how can i use this to take input from user.

Answer (score 1):

```
int add = 1;
int before = 7;    
string newNumber = string.Format("{0}{1}", add, before);
```

If you want to convert the int afterwards into an `int` again, you could use [int.Parse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [int.TryParse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for it.

Answer (score 1):

another one

```
string.Concat(1, 13);
```

to get a number back

```
Convert.ToInt32(string.Concat(1, 13));
```

Answer (score 1):

Using just math:

```
int num = 7;
int add = 1;
int newNumber = add * (int)Math.Pow(10, 1 + (int)Math.Log10(num)) + num;
```

Comment: That doesn't compile because Math.Pow returns a double and a double * int is double + int is still double and there is no implicit conversion from double to int.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the integer to a string first and concatenate them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
static int main(){

    int num1 = 7;
    int num2 = 1;
    int num3 = 3;

    string strNum1 = string.Concat(num2.ToString(), num1.ToString());
    string strNum2 = string.Concat(num3.ToString(), num2.ToString(), num1.ToString());
    int newNumber1 = int.Parse(strNum1);
    int newNumber2 = int.Parse(strNum2);

    Console.WriteLine(IsPrime(num1)); // True
    Console.WriteLine(IsPrime(newNumber1)); // True
    Console.WriteLine(IsPrime(newNumber2)); // True
}


/// <summary>
/// Used to determine if number is a prime number
/// </summary>
/// <param name="value">The whole number.</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static bool IsPrime(int value)
{
    if (value == 1)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if ((value & 1) == 0)
    {
        if (value == 2)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    for (int i = 3; (i * i) <= value; i += 2)
    {
        if ((value % i) == 0)
            return false;
    }
    return value != 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int n1=Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());    //let n1=7
int n2=Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());    //let n2=1
int result=n2*10+n1;   //result=1*10+7=17
```

Now for checking prime no.

```
int flag=0;
for(int i=2;i<result;i++)
{
    if(result%i==0)
    {
        flag=1;
    }
}
if(flag==0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("No. is prime");
}
```